# Exception: net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["tag"] not found when doing a rebuild

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i get this exception when doing rebuild for a build that ran perfectly in jenkins.
all params looks good.
i use Slave Prerequisites Plugin.
and top-level-maven execution

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it - the Slave Prerequisites Plugin.
you have set a name for the node selection parameter.
it can be used without a name, but hen again rebuild will fail.